# Double-clicking a window’s title bar to minimize it in Mavericks

Tags: macos, dock, window-manager

After upgrading to Mavericks I’m no longer able to minimize a window to the Dock by double-clicking on its title bar. How do I get this functionality back?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Go to the Dock section of System Preferences and check “Double-click a window’s title bar to minimize”.

[image: Screenshot of Dock window]

Comment: Comment on ollie's behalf - "that didnt work for me..i domnt see the option under dock"

Comment: If I remember correctly, this option was only added in Mavericks. (Before that, double-clicking a title bar would always minimize the window.) Perhaps Ollie is using a previous version of OS X?

Answer (score 1):

System Preferences

Appearance

Second section,select   Double-click a window's....

Comment: In Mavericks, it's under System Preferences > Dock